# How to run pipeline in parallel?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

How can I go about parallelizing the following pipeline? Each string from the **test_proj_choices** list needs to run in parallel. I have tried using the parallel function inside of the for each loop but I keep getting syntax errors. I appreciate any help. I have been having a hard time with this.

```
pipeline 
{
    agent {label 'UH60V && SCADE'}

    stages
    {
            
                stage ('Test') {
                steps
                {
                    script
                    {
                        def test_proj_choices = ['ADC', 'CDU_C', 'DCU', 'DISP_A_REND', 'DISP_PROC', 'EGI', 'FD', 'FLT', 'FMS_C', 'IFF', 'liblO', 'libNGC', 'libSC', 'MISCMP_MP', 'MISCMP_GP', 'NAV_MGR', 'RADALT', 'SYS', 'SYSIO1553', 'SYSIO429', 'SYSRED', 'TACAN', 'VOR_ILS', 'VPA', 'WAAS', 'WCA']
                        for (choice in test_proj_choices) 
                        {
                            stage ("${choice}") 
                            {
                                echo "Running ${choice}"
                                build job: "SCADE_Suite_Testing", parameters: [string(name: "SCADE_SUITE_TEST_PROJECT", value: choice), string(name: "SCADE_SUITE_TEST_ACTION", value: "all"), string(name: "CLEARCASE_VIEW_ROOT", value: "myview")] 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51059802/924036

Comment: I am having a hard time applying that to my pipeline. I seem to get syntax errors. Can you help me apply it to my example?